# Getting python exceptions printed the normal way with PyObjC

Tags: python, objective-c, exception, pyobjc

I'm getting errors like this:

> 2010-07-13 20:43:15.131
>   Python[1527:60f] main: Caught
>   OC_PythonException: :
>   LoginMenuSet instance has no attribute
>   'play_sound'

That's with this code:

```
@try {
    [section loop]; //Loop through section
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
}
```

I want the python exception to be printed normally with the traceback and everything else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own solution:

In Objective-C class:

```
@try {
        [section loop]; //Loop through section
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        [self exception: [[exception userInfo] valueForKey: @"__pyobjc_exc_traceback__"]];
    }
```

In python pyobjc subclass:

```
def exception_(self,trace):
        traceback.print_tb(trace)
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate_(None) #Accept no errors
```

I, of-course, imported the traceback module.

Answer (score 9):

One trick to see Python exceptions is to call `objc.setVerbose(1)`. This makes PyObjC slightly more verbose and causes it to print Python stack traces when converting exceptions from Python to Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but since asking this question I did find my own solution eventually.

I forgot to answer my own question but I'll do that below.

Comment: For completeness, you must first `import objc`.